# Why "display:none;" does not work with the bootstrap media request?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, media-queries

I'm working on a responsive web page using bootstrap. I want to replace a image (make one visible and the other invisible), after reducing the width of the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/mbe5huxa/

```css
@media(max-width:767px) {
    .monitors {
          border: solid blue 8px;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="monitors">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/9574/pexels-photo-large.jpeg" alt="Background is loading"></a>
            </div>
```

It works in JSfiddle, but for some reason not working correctly in my local CSS (I write CSS using SASS). In my case, the image of the blue border appears after you reduce the page width, but the image does not disappear.
Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should post the code block that's not working.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities - You do not need to write a media query for this; Bootstrap has smart hide/show classes that will do this for you.

Comment: @Michael_B The block of code above works on JSFiddle but does not work locally on my computer.

Comment: @RobertC Thank you very much, this is a great option! But I also need to make some other changes to the CSS depending on the screen size, so it is important to understand why the border CSS rule works, and display the CSS rule is not working.

Comment: The Fiddle you posted has `display:none` working as expected...

Comment: Media queries don't operate in a vacuum. Code appearing after your media query can override rules in the media query. There may be other cascade or specificity issues. That's why I suggested you post more code.

Comment: @RobertC Yes, I can't understand why it doesn't working with my local web page. Perhaps something related to Bootstrap or SASS affects it?..

Comment: If the Fiddle shows your media query working absent your local web page, but your local web page (which I assume has even more CSS) has it nonfunctional... then the issue must reside with the larger CSS rather than the snippet you've provided.

Comment: This is a cascading issue, not a bootstrap or css issue. Use your browser inspector to troubleshoot and find the overwriting property.